# trying to send a label to a zpl printer

Tags: python, networking, printing, zpl

I am new to this and I have an issue.
First the setup:
I am connected to a printer (Zebra ZD 420) thru an ethernet switch. I setup both PC and printer to static IP's and the printer has 192.168.1.35.
Thru a python script I am trying to send a label (it has been saved as label.prn) to the printer. I found an example on the internet and it works as found but when I add the lines to read the content of the file it always give me "Error with the connection". Here's the code:

```
import socket              
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
host = "192.168.1.35" 
port = 9100   
try:
    mysocket.connect((host, port)) #connecting to host
    s.bind((host, port))
    with open(label.prn, 'r') as h:
        lines = h.readlines
        for line in lines:
            print(line.strip())
            arr = bytes(line.strip(), 'utf-8')
            mysocket.send(b, arr)#using bytes
    mysocket.close () #closing connection
except:
    print("Error with the connection")
```

and here's the content of the label.prn file:

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
```

^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR3,3~SD8^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW609
^LL0203
^LS0
^FT66,161^BQN,2,6
^FH^FDLA,07/07/2023^FS
^FT401,161^BQN,2,6
^FH^FDLA,22:10:23^FS
^FT55,190^A0N,28,40^FH^FD07/07/2023^FS
^FT403,190^A0N,28,36^FH^FD22:10:23^FS
^FT269,118^A0N,81,117^FH^FDR^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

I am sending the label.prn file to the printer thru Zebra's own software and it prints OK so I know the file and the format is good.

Comment: 1) "I found an example on the internet and it works" <-- so is the code you posted your edits to working code? If so, what did you add? 2) Get rid of the try/except so you can see the raw error.

Comment: If you sent the ZPL from a text editor, to the printer, with TCP/IP generic text based driver from your windows PC, does it print the label as expected?

Comment: Hi ckhan,The original code is as following: "import socket              
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)         
host = "192.168.1.35" 
port = 9100   
try:           
 mysocket.connect((host, port)) #connecting to host
 mysocket.send(b"^XA^A0N,50,50^FO50,50^FDSocket Test^FS^XZ")#using bytes
 mysocket.close () #closing connection
except:
 print("Error with the connection")
".

Comment: Hi EdHayes3, I used the Zebra send file to printer and it prints exactly how I needed.

Comment: Get rid of the try and except. Its starting to look like you just cut and pasted some code from a different program : the `s.bind((host, port))` looks like you pulled it from a different script that was openign the socket manually. I'm guessing if you remove the try/except, you'll see an error saying 's' doesn't exist.